# API for the new Screen View feature in iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

iOS 9.3 is supposed to have a new Screen View feature where the screen can be viewed on another iOS device. See [iOS in Education](http://www.apple.com/education/preview/)

Does anyone know whether there's an API in the new SDK for this?